# Как запустить Activity С помощью разных Button? Java

Tags: java, activity, android-intent

мне необходимо запустить другой экран и перенести в него информацию полученную от нажатия одной из кнопок. Нужно чтобы кнопки запускали следующее Activity и переносили информацию о нажатой кнопке.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
Button EngBtn;
Button FrBtn;
Button EspBtn;
Button RusBtn;
Button GermBtn;
int Lang = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EngBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.EngBtn);
    EngBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    FrBtn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.FrBtn);
    FrBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    EspBtn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.EspBtn);
    EspBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    RusBtn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.RusBtn);
    RusBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    GermBtn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.GermBtn);
    GermBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

}
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.EngBtn:
            Lang=1;
            break;
        case R.id.FrBtn:
            Lang=2;
            break;
        case R.id.EspBtn:
            Lang=3;
            break;
        case R.id.RusBtn:
            Lang=4;
            break;
        case R.id.GermBtn:
            Lang=5;
            break;
        default:
            break;

    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913592/start-an-activity-with-a-parameter

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод onClick() дополняем вызовом активити с параметром:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.EngBtn:
        Lang=1;
        break;
    case R.id.FrBtn:
        Lang=2;
        break;
    case R.id.EspBtn:
        Lang=3;
        break;
    case R.id.RusBtn:
        Lang=4;
        break;
    case R.id.GermBtn:
        Lang=5;
        break;
    default:
        break;
  }
  Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
  i.putExtra("lang", Lang);
  startActivity(i);
  finish();
}
```

Получаем в другой активити (обычно в методе onCreate():

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
int Lang = b.getInt("lang");
```

PS: в Java имена переменных принято писать с маленькой буквы - lang.